# Remove implicit margin spacing in Grid cell

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to build a Grid layout. In Firefox Inspector it looks like this:

[image: Cell with what seems like margins]

Around `Drivers` there seems to be some *margin*. When I look into the element however, it has neither *padding* nor *margin*.
So am I wondering where can find/see which "spacing" it is using for a Grid cell and how can I minimize the spacing?

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on how you have defined the grid. Check your grid gaps, you justify.

Try this:

```
justify-content: start;
```

It will align to the beginning of each row, assuming direction horizontal. If it removes the gap then you can take it from there experimenting on how you want things to align.

Edit*
Check your **grid-template-columns** also, it might be the size of your column.

Comment: When I explicitly use e.g. `1em` in `grid-template-columns`, it indeed is as big. Is there any way to have the column use a minimal size? I thought `min-content` would do that but apparently not.

Comment: @abergmeier assuming you have 2 columns and you already know the exact size (say 50px) you want for thr first column you could do this grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr; You could also try fit-content(). Min-content should work but it depends on how it is measuring the contents in the column(I am not sure how it does this after rotating), I see you have rotated the text, so it might be using the unrotated length of the text.